# Error : steal.js INFO: Model.js - undefined destroyed When i call destroy() function in CanJS

Tags: javascript, ejs, canjs

I have the example , when i call destroy function, it delete item, but when i refresh brower, it seem not delete data to database.

```
Musics = can.Control({
        init : function(element, options) {
            var el = this.element;
            Music.findAll({}, function(musics) {
                el.html(can.view('view/listMusic.ejs', {
                    musics : musics
                }))
            }, function(error) {
                console.log("Erro:" + error)
            });
        },

        "#add-btn click" : function() {
            can.route.attr({route:"update",type:"add"});
        },
        ".btn-edit click" : function(li) {
            can.route.attr({route:"update/:type",type:"edit",id:""+li.val()+""});
        },
        ".btn-delete click" : function(li) {
           li.closest('tr').data('music').destroy();
        },
  })
```

File listMusic.ejs:

```
<tbody class="tbody-music">
                <% list(musics, function(music){ %>
                    <tr <%= (el)-> el.data('music', music) %>>
                        <td class="col-md-1 col-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox">
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-md-5">
                            <%= music.musicName %>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-md-3">
                            <%= music.musicGenre %>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-md-3 col-edit">
                            <button class="btn-edit" value="<%= music.musicId %>"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn-delete" value="<%= music.musicId %>"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <% }) %>
            </tbody>
```

File Model.js :

```
steal("jquery", "can", function() {
Music = can.Model({
    findAll : 'GET /api',
    findOne : 'GET /api/{id}',
    destroy : "DELETE /api/{id}",
}, {})
```

})

Then, How can i use destroy function in CanJS ? I do it same to contact Manager 
Here is the link : http://ilearnhub.in/tutorials/canjs/contactManager

Comment: EJS in canjs is outdated take a look at the site "EJS is incompatable with can.Component and should be avoided for new projects. It will still be maintained up to 3.0 and potentially after. Projects using EJS should consider switching to can.stache." https://canjs.com/docs/can.ejs.html

Comment: in this example, i didnt use can.Component . so that ejs file is not involve destroy function.